# How to connect a set of DICOM images to its Scout image?

Tags: image, image-processing, dicom

Given a set of images I have to find the scout image which contains that set. Now I'm using study ID (0020,000D) and Scan Option (0018, 0022): when set_of_images.StudyID=x.StudyID and x.scanOption="SCOUT MODE" then x is scout. This actually worked for the majority of the folder I have been given but I found a case with multiple scouts with the same StudyID. Can you suggest a better way to do this? I really don't know what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See section 2.2.1 of http://www.dclunie.com/medical-image-faq/html/part2.html.

At least in MR, the closest, *smaller* localizer series in terms of series number is typically the best choice (e.g. if you have localizers with series numbers 2, 3, and 11. Series number 9 probably best matches the localizer with series number 3).

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood: do I have to check using the math in the link every series in a folder with the the same StudyID and what do I have to find to say "this is the scout"? I can use these formula but I don't know what to look at...

Comment: From that first bullet: "Determining which image or images is/are the localizer for a particular set of images: some vendors send this information in the "Referenced Image Sequence" attribute, in the case of CT it may simply be an image with an "Image Type" value 3 of "LOCALIZER" (this doesn't apply to MR) and the same Frame of Reference UID, and in other cases one just has to search the entire set of images and find other likely candidates that are orthogonal or close to it based on "Image Orientation(Patient)"."